# How can i assign a random material from a list in Python

Tags: python, materials, scripting

Ive been trying to write a script to assign random materials based on probabilities without success.

the working code is this:

```
item = bpy.context.object
            if random.random() < 0.2:
                item.data.materials.append(bpy.data.materials["crustylava"])
            else:
                item.data.materials.append(bpy.data.materials["magma"])
```

I tried using a variation of this:

```
import secrets
import random

foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

print(random.choices(foo, weights=[1, 0, 0, 10, 1]))
```

which i wrote:

```
foo = [bpy.data.materials["crustylava"], bpy.data.materials["magma"]]
mat1 = random.choices((foo, weights=[1, 0]))
mat2 = random.choices((foo, weights=[0, 1]))

item = bpy.context.object
    if random.random() < 0.2:
        item.data.materials.append(mat1)
    else:
        item.data.materials.append(mat2)
```

It says that materials.append expects a material 'type' not a list. Sorry for the noob question but I'm losing my sanity over this =D

Comment: `random.choices((foo, weights=[1, 0]))` is just a complicated way to write `[foo[0]]`. The equivalent of your working code is `item.data.materials.append( random.choices(foo, weights=[2,8])[0] )`.

Comment: thanks man!!!! this is spot on!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`random.choices` returns a list.**

```
>>> random.choices(
choices(self, population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1)
Return a k sized list of population elements chosen with replacement.
If the relative weights or cumulative weights are not specified,
the selections are made with equal probability.
```

Error message is pretty self-explanatory here, in that `choices` is returning a list, as explained in doc string above A test print from the letters example

```
['d']
```

which for the second example you are trying to append a list to the materials collection, not a material. Just like `['d']` is a list containing the character d, not a character.

If we are sure the list contains an element can  `mat = somelist[0]` and  `mat = somelist.pop()` to get the first and last.  (or the other way `somelist.pop(0) , somelist[-1]` respectively.

Test script, (simply used material list as test case rather than key by name)

```
import bpy
from random import choices, random
# require at least 2 materials
assert len(bpy.data.materials) >= 2
foo = bpy.data.materials[-2:] # last 2 of all materials

mat1 = choices(foo, weights=[1, 0]).pop()
mat2 = choices(foo, weights=[0, 1]).pop()

ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data
me.materials.append(
        mat1 if random() < 0.2 else mat2
        )
```